# Convert factory-class and factory-method to factory in Services.xml

Tags: php, ffmpeg, symfony

I'm using Symfony3 and I [noticed](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) that `factory-class` and `factory-method` don't exist anymore, but `factory` does exist.

This is rather frustrating because I would like to use [pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle](https://github.com/pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle), but the `services.xml` seems to be pre-3.0.

[image: factory-class and factory-method]

As you can see the 4 red marked attributes are the problem:

```
factory-class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class%" factory-method="create"
factory-class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffprobe.class%" factory-method="create"
```

**Example(Symfony3 version):**

```
services:
    newsletter_manager:
        class:   NewsletterManager
        factory: [NewsletterManagerFactory, createNewsletterManager]
```

**Question:**

How do I update the services.xml for it to work correctly with Symfony3?

**What I have tried:**

I have tried combining the two without much success and using `factory` instead. But apparantly "factory" is not allowed either.

**Errors:**

```
$ php bin/console server:run
```

The error I am getting :

> The attribute 'factory-class' is not allowed.

[image: error]

Comment: This bundle is not compatible with Symfony 3. The only solution is to use an alternative, fork it or try to contribute to it, or write your own.

Comment: @Gerry so even if I add the factory element, it won't work at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downside of bundles, especially with the current switch from 2 to 3, is that you are dependent on their maintainers to update the code to support the new version.

The normal procedure to fix this:

- Fork the repository
- Apply the fix in the services.xml
- Submit a pull-request
- Wait for the maintainer to merge it.

If the maintainer is not responding to your pull-request, or you really need it now. You can add the link to the fork in the composer.json repositories list.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository

And then it will install your forked version, which contains the fix.

Comment: I've have omitted this part in my answer. It's effectively the right way; when you encounter this kind of problems with a bundle, especially if that not involves a lot of code, you should make a fix and propose it to the owner, and, of course, use it before the fix is merged.
Thank's for your job.

Answer (score 3):

Since `factory-class` and `factory-method` are deprecated in Symfony,
you have to use :

XML :

```
<services>
    <service id="dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg" class="NewsletterManager">
        <factory class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class%" method="create" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Or YAML :

```
services:
    dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg:
        class:   NewsletterManager
        factory: [%dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class%, create]
```

The first argument represents the `class` attribute, and the second argument represents the `method` attribute.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Answer (score 0):

I added the `<factory></factory>` elements and defined the attributes class and method inside of them. And I was able to run the server without a problem, for now.

```
<service id="dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg" class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class%" lazy="true">
    <factory class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffmpeg.class%" method="create"></factory>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="ffmpeg.binaries">%dubture_ffmpeg.binary%</argument>
        <argument key="ffprobe.binaries">%dubture_ffprobe.binary%</argument>
        <argument key="timeout">%dubture_ffmpeg.binary_timeout%</argument>
        <argument key="ffmpeg.threads">%dubture_ffmpeg.threads_count%</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument id="logger" type="service"/>
</service>

<service id="dubture_ffmpeg.ffprobe" class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffprobe.class%" lazy="true">
    <factory class="%dubture_ffmpeg.ffprobe.class%" method="create"></factory>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="ffmpeg.binaries">%dubture_ffmpeg.binary%</argument>
        <argument key="ffprobe.binaries">%dubture_ffprobe.binary%</argument>
    </argument>
    <argument id="logger" type="service"/>
</service>
```

Comment: This isn't the right thing to do if you're not the maintainer of the bundle (in which case http://stackoverflow.com/a/34881959/330267 is the right answer).